# Wordpress navigate within a category

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks

Im working on a project that requires the end user to navigate the website based on the category they visit. eg.

http://domain.com/category-name/post-name

I have the permalinks setup to where it always shows the category name before the post name.
However sometimes if a post is assigned to two categories it will show the name from the other category in the url.

Im doing queries based on a category ID but I want it to always display the same category name once the user has entered into a specific category.

Does this make sense to anyone? has anyone come across this issue before?
I know wordpress is not built to work this way, but I am trying to make this scenario work for me.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Check out http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-permalink/

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_the_category( $id ); to get an array of all the post's categories. You can then display content related to both. Otherwise you could use cookies to track the last category visited.